# Connecting through webservice

Tags: php, objective-c, web-services, ipad, nsurl

Im trying to insert into a database on a webserver. Im using MYSQL,Appache and PHP

Xcode

```
*-(IBAction)saveRecord:(id)sender{
    UITextField *description_txtfield = (UITextField*)[self.tableView viewWithTag:11];
    description_string = description_txtfield.text;
    NSLog(description_string);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.140/~admin/qw/"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:description_string forKey:@"product_name"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {    

    if (request.responseStatusCode == 400) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid code");        
    } else if (request.responseStatusCode == 403) {
        NSLog(@"Code already used");
    } else if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
        NSLog(@"OK");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unexpected error");
    }
     }*

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription);
}   
index.php has the following code inside to handle insert.

Function redeem() {

        // Check for required parameters
        if (isset($_POST["product_name"])) {

            // Put parameters into local variables
            $rw_app_id = $_POST["product_name"];
            // Add tracking of redemption
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO inventory (product_name) VALUES (?)");
            $stmt->bind_param($rw_app_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

        }
        return false;

    }
```

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong here. I keep getting Invalid Code which is Bad Request-400. Help! this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your php code correctly, it looks to me like your `redeem`function will always hit the `sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');` line at the bottom of the function.

Is there any case where your `redeem` function returns true and doesn't send a `400` code back?

Comment: i took it out but its still not going through. I fig. that was giving me some problem but i told it out and im getting an unexpected error from this method - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request. Would the fact that im using IP address in my url cause a problem?

Comment: how can i make sure the index.php is recieving a value? I can query the database to list all the products and display it on my page. thats working find. it seems as though the index.php page isnt reciving the value when i hit the save button on my app. any way to check this out?

Comment: No, using a numeric IP address isn't the problem.  Maybe you need to send a `200` response back from the php side so your client's `requestFinished` method will report back that all was a success?

Comment: not getting the 200 response. i dont think its recieving a value.